Import Content Type in STRAPI
Is there any way to transfer Content-Type Builer in Strapi to another Strapi source code ?
i want to move all my collection types in Content-Type Builder to another Strapi source code, but i don't see any documents about it, it has only data transfer.

Strapi Content Types are generated and stored as files under /src/api/apiName, so to move your content types structure to another strapi installation you gonna need to copy folders files from one /src/api/apiName to another /src/api/apiName
Note that if you are using components you also gonna need to copy components
Note that you can't copy apiName to anotherApiName directly (you can by copying attributes from schema json. A folder for components and name of component should also remain same.
For typescript project that might not work, the easiest approach is to create new Content Type and copy schema.json attributes content to newly created api
